# How to return a deferred promise and create a model with Ember.Deferred?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a `User.current()` in my application, which pulls data from my server using `$.getJSON('/users/current', function(data) { ... });`. I am using the Singleton method that Discourse uses, which does the following:

```
Dashboard.Singleton = Ember.Mixin.create({
        // See https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/mixins/singleton.js

        current: function() {
                if (!this._current) {
                        this._current = this.createCurrent();
                }
                return this._current;
        },

        createCurrent: function() {
                return this.create({});
        }
});
```

And in my `User` singleton model, I've rewritten `createCurrent` as follows:

```
Dashboard.User.reopenClass(Dashboard.Singleton, {
        createCurrent: function() {
                return Ember.Deferred.promise(function(p) {
                        return p.resolve($.getJSON('/users/current').then(function(data) {
                                return Dashboard.User.create(data);
                        }));
                });
        }
});
```

User is a normal Ember object model:

```
Dashboard.User = Ember.Object.extend({

});
```

This does request the data from the server, but the function is not setting `User.current()` correctly - when I inspect it, `User.current()` has none of the properties that should be set, such as `name`.

How can I return and set the current user using Ember's deferred and promises?

Comment: What is the user model?  Plain Ember Object?

Comment: Yes. I'll update my question with what `User` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cause you're returning the promise in place of the user.

Why don't you create the user, then fill in the properties later.

Or use the Promise Proxy pattern that Ember Data uses (the promise can be used as the object once resolved)

```
DS.PromiseObject = Ember.ObjectProxy.extend(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin);

function promiseObject(promise) {
  return DS.PromiseObject.create({ promise: promise });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I return the promise that the user will be returned?

Comment: if you want, but then you'll always have to access the model using promise.then(function(record){//here it is}}));

Comment: which may be what you want if you always want to wait until the user is defined

Comment: If I created the user and then filled in the properties, wouldn't I have to use `.set()` on each property I want to fill in?

Comment: nah, there is a shortcut ;)  `model.setProperties(data)`

Comment: Okay, I'll try that out. I am curious though, do you know if it's possible to return data from a promise without having to call `.then()`? I.e. set `User.current()` in the promise and return it, rather than using `setProperties()`?

Comment: Ember Data uses a PromiseObject which essentially proxies values through to and from the object through the promise (allowing you to return the promise and just pretend it's the object.

Comment: The `PromiseObject` and `PromiseProxyMixin` code worked! Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

Since $.getJSON('/users/current') returns a promise, might as well use that.

```
createCurrent: function() {
                return $.getJSON('/users/current').then(function(data) {
                       return Dashboard.User.create(data);
                });
    }
```

Then you need to keep in mind that createCurrent returns a promise, not the object itself so you will need to:

```
current: function() {
            if (!this._current) {
                    var that = this;
                    this.fetching = true;
                    this.createCurrent().then(function(val) {
                        that.fetching = false;
                        that._current = val;
                    });
            }
            return this._current;
    },
```

Comment: the current will return undefined until the promise is resolved, this code doesn't run asynchronously.

Comment: i know current will be undefined until the promise is resolved. Why is that an issue? What code are you referring to that doesn't run asynchronously?

Comment: Because, ever time you call, this.current() you'd create a new instance, making a new ajax call until it resolves and you'd keep getting undefined back.

Comment: And I mean the asynchronous portion won't block making sure the return this._current has something.

Comment: Thats not true, the caching is right there on the second line: if (!this._current). You mean to tell me you write code that makes an AJAX call block so that you wait until you have a value before proceeding?

Comment: asynchronous mistakes are easy to make, that's fine, I'll setup a jsbin and show you your mistake

Comment: Here's an example, i call the current 24 times, it makes 8 ajax calls, returns different instances for the first while, then finally lands on a single instance.  Unfortunately the first 9 calls got undefined back and don't have a way of knowing if/when it'll be resolved/available, and the next 8 are pointing to different objects.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/25/edit

Comment: wow, @kingpin2k what a contrived example to try and prove my pattern wrong. First 'Singleton' is... well.. a singleton so your example of trying to create multiple instance of the singleton is quite silly. But none the less, here is a more sane fiddle of the pattern I explained: http://jsbin.com/eJosIRa/1/

Comment: lol, by contrived I assume you mean normal and you're for some reason offended that I told you your code was wrong.  My example exposed how your code in no way implemented a singleton pattern that could work in an asynchronous world. You changed your code to try and make it work in your jsbin, but it's still wrong, it makes 24 calls to the server, for what should be 1 call.  Your original code is wrong and so is this code.